# Help identifying motobecane bike

Tags: identify-this-bike, vintage

Any and all information about this motobecane would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Stem shifters and mixte frame suggest the 70s.  And apparently those brakes were being made in the late 50s and later.

Comment: Apparently some of those brakes have the date on the back.

Comment: Definitely has all the hallmarks of a 70's bike boom mixte frame. Even the rack is accurate for the period. Motobecane then was a french bike company and quite popular along with Raleigh at the time for mid range bikes. The company since went out of business and the Motobecane label was bought up and is now used on budget bikes out of China.

Answer (score 5):

It looks like a 1978 ladies Mirage with a different seat.
[Catalog page](http://www.velo-pages.com/main.php?g2_itemId=33071&g2_imageViewsIndex=1):
[image]

[Parts list](http://www.velo-pages.com/main.php?g2_itemId=33089&g2_imageViewsIndex=1):
[image]

In 1978 Motobecane went to an SR AX crank. In 1977 and 1976 it was a Tourney crank but those bikes had drop bars.